# how to add kernel boot parameters

Tags: grub2, kernel, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

I'm looking for a way to fix this bug the way described [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=727579).

But I don't know how to edit boot options in Kubuntu. In my distribution there's no `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file and also the `grub.cfg` in same folder does not have a line starting with `kernel`.

I'm really clueless about adding these options!

Answer (score 1):

The `/boot/grub/menu.lst` was a very old way of configuring GRUB and it's boot options. I think I used to use it like that in Ubuntu 10.10 and below. Right now, if you are using a updated version of Kubuntu, the option should be in `/etc/default/grub`

Just do something like:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (To edit via terminal)
`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` (To edit via GUI)

The option you want to edit is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

You can either add what you want after the **splash** parameterin the first line or add inside the quoted part in the second part.

After that, save the file and type in the terminal `update-grub` so the grub gets updated and adds what changes you have done to the boot part. Then just reboot the PC and enjoy the change.